# Storing enum in separate table

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0

I have entity Student and it has field like enum City. I know how to store enums in jpa via @Enumerated annotation, but I want to store enum in separate table and have foreign key from Student to City. But I have no idea how to implement.

**City**

```
public enum City {
   PAVLOGRAD("Pavlograd")
  ,DNEPR("Dnepr");

  private String shortName;

   City(String shortName) {
      this.shortName = shortName;
   }

   public String getShortName() {
      return shortName;
   }
}
```

**Student**

```
public class Student implements Serializable {

   @Id
   @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO) 
   private Integer id;

   @Enumerated(EnumType.ORDINAL)
   private City city;
}
```

Comment: Well, just create the other city table, and add a foreign key constraint between on the student table's city column, referencing city's primary key (which should contain the ordinal of the City enum). But using an enum for City looks like a really bad idea. Do you really want to modify, recompile and redeploy your app every time you want a new city?

Comment: Thanks, JB Nizet! Do you mean I need mark City with @Entity annotation (with adding id to it) and create OneToOne relationship from Student? Yes, I'll recompile every time.

Comment: No, I never said that. I mean't what I said: create a city table, make its primary key an integer containing the enum's ordinal, and create a foreign key constraint.

Comment: Please, change my code, I can't understand your solution

Comment: There is absolutely nothing to change in the code. Again, read my comment. All I said was to create a table (that's done using SQL, not by modifying Java code), and to add a foreign key constraint (again SQL, not Java code).

Comment: I see. Is it correct to use @JoinColumn annotation on enum field?

Comment: No. And there is no point.

Comment: What @JBNizet is trying to say: When you create a table City and you use the ordinal value as primary key then you have to change nothing. But this solution is pretty useless why should you want to have a table that has the same values as the enum in the code! So if you want to make it useful change the enum to an entity and make a ManyToOne relationship.